# how to map callback Function with Java native access (JNA)

Tags: java, winapi, jna

How can i set up windows hook with `WH_FOREGROUNDIDLE` and the following call back Functions

```
DWORD CALLBACK ForegroundIdleProc( __in int code, DWORD wParam, LONG lParam );
```

I am trying to detect when a thread/process goes idle.

I have obtained the `threadProccessId` by using the following functions:

```
GetForegroundWindow -> GetWindowThreadProcessId.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static interface ForegroundIdleProc extends Callback(){
   int invoke(int code, int wParam , NativeLong lParam);
 }

 /*....Usage....*/
 ForegroundIdleProc proc = new ForegroundIdleProc(){
   int invoke(int code, int wParam , NativeLong lParam){
      /* Handle callback */
       /*Make sure you define this function first.*/
       return NativeLibrary.Instance.CallNextHookEx(NULL , code , wParam , lParam);
   } 
 }

 NativeLibrary.Instance.SetWindowsHookEx(WH_FOREGROUNDIDLE , proc , etc etc);
```

**EDIT: Added a return statement.**

Comment: What should i return? when i override the invoke button it requests me to return something. msdn says CallNextHookEx should be called when ForegroundIdleProc returns 0. i'm confused here a little.

Comment: According to MSDN  `If code is less than zero, the hook procedure must return the value returned by CallNextHookEx.

If code is greater than or equal to zero, it is highly recommended that you call CallNextHookEx and return the value it returns; otherwise, other applications that have installed WH_FOREGROUNDIDLE hooks will not receive hook notifications and may behave incorrectly as a result. If the hook procedure does not call CallNextHookEx, the return value should be zero.`

Answer (score 0):

Extend StdCallCallback instead of Callback in order to get the callback called with the correct calling convention.  Under win32 the macro "CALLBACK" usually resolves to _stdcall.